# CakePHP 1.3 Find Condition with CONCAT multiple fields Next one hour records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp-1.3, concatenation

Below is my Find condition to get records matching <= next 1 hr show timings.

```
$conditions = array(
    "CONCAT(`showdate`,' ',`hours`,':',`minutes`,':00') <" => "DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)",
    "CONCAT(`showdate`,' ',`hours`,':',`minutes`,':00') >=" => "NOW()");
```

If run same query in PHPMyAdmin - SQL prompt, its working as below:

```
SELECT * FROM `showtimes` WHERE CONCAT( `showdate` , ' ', `hours` , ':', `minutes` , ':00' ) < DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) AND CONCAT( `showdate` , ' ', `hours` , ':', `minutes` , ':00' ) >= NOW( ) LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Above MySQL query is running fine, but when I check with CakePHP Find, its not working.

Below is combination for same:

```
$conditions = array(
    "CONCAT(`showdate`,' ',`hours`,':',`minutes`,':00') <" => "DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)",
    "CONCAT(`showdate`,' ',`hours`,':',`minutes`,':00') >=" => "NOW()",
    );

pr($conditions);
$this->Showtime->recursive = -1;
$areas = $this->Showtime->find('all',
            array(
                    'conditions' => $conditions,
                    'limit' => $limit,
                    'offset' => $offset,
                    'group' => 'Showtime.id',
                )
            );

pr($areas);
```

Any help or ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the condition, I found working for me:

```
$conditions = array("CONCAT(`hours`,':',`minutes`) <=" => date('H:i', strtotime('+1 hour')), "CONCAT(`hours`,':',`minutes`) >=" => date('H:i'));
```

Hope it helps to the community members !

Suggestions always welcome.

Comment: "Inventive" solution - for that you should be using date functions in the database rather than doing string comparisons